# How can I upload or copy a file from an FTP to a S3 server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, ftp

I'm trying to write a script that's able to upload or copy a file from an FTP to a S3 server.

To try to upload the file to S3 I'm using a method that I used before to upload images using a form.

The method is this one:

```
public static function uploadFileToS3($from, $to, $bucket) {

    $s3 = new AmazonS3();

    AmazonLib::useSSL($s3);

    $file_upload_response= $s3->create_object($bucket, $to, array(
        "fileUpload" => $from,
        "acl" => AmazonS3::ACL_PUBLIC
    ));

    return $file_upload_response->isOK();

}
```

When I call this method I send this params:

`$from` -> the path for the file that's in the FTP

`$to` -> the folder where I want to upload the file

`$bucket` -> the bucket which contains the folder from $to

When I try to do the upload, the error I get is this one:

```
2016-04-19 11:25:09 (CEST) 2 Advertencia fopen(192.168.XXX.XXX/path/to/file/my_file.pdf): failed to open stream: The file or directory not exists
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution downloading the file using `fpt_get()` and then uploading the file using my method. Finally I remove the file from the local machine using `unlink()`

Comment: Your solution is time consuming and You have to execute total three process.

Is there any another way for this?